# Как можно применить свою написанную функцию на list-object?

Tags: python, функции, list, список

У меня есть написанная функция, но когда я применяю её Python выдаёт ошибку `'str' object has no attribute 'preprocess'`.

```
tweets_text_preprocess = []
for string in range(len(tweets_text)):
   tweets_text_preprocess[string] = tweets_text[string].preprocess()
```

`tweets_text` - это list, объекты которого string. Я не могу понять, почему код не работает.

Comment: Ну вы сами же говорите, что `tweets_text[string]` - это строка. И откуда у строки метод `preprocess()`? Может вы хотели написать `tweets_text_preprocess[string] = preprocess(tweets_text[string])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, что вы хотите сделать, то это делается так:

```
tweets_text_preprocess = list(map(preprocess, tweets_text))
```

Это в случае, если вы хотите применить функцию `preprocess` к каждому элементу списка `tweets_text` и получить из результатов новый список.

Другой вариант - использовать *списковое сокращение*:

```
tweets_text_preprocess = [preprocess(text) for text in tweets_text]
```

Можно сделать и обычным циклом, но эти два способа наиболее "питонячие".